# Error message in ggplot, has to do with my call for ( family="Lato")

Tags: r, ggplot2

I am getting this warning message below for a ggplot. it only gives me an empty plot with the following warning messages below
Warning messages:
1: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :
no font could be found for family "Lato"
2: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :
no font could be found for family "Lato"
3: In grid.Call.graphics(C_text, as.graphicsAnnot(x$label), x$x, x$y,  :
no font could be found for family "Lato"

```
    data10 <- structure(list(GROUP = c("LLL", "LLL", "LLL", "LRL", "LRL", "LRL",
"RLR", "RLR", "RLR", "RRR", "RRR", "RRR"), conditon2 = c("Midline_Ret_L",
"No Midline crossing_Ret_L", "Midline crossing_Ret_L", "Midline_Trans_R",
"No Midline crossing_Trans_R", "Midline crossing_Trans_R", "Midline_Trans_L",
"No Midline crossing_Trans_L", "Midline crossing_Trans_L", "Midline_Ret_R",
"No Midline crossing_Ret_R", "Midline crossing_Ret_R"), condition = c("Midline",
"No Midline crossing", "Midline crossing", "Midline", "No Midline crossing",
"Midline crossing", "Midline", "No Midline crossing", "Midline crossing",
"Midline", "No Midline crossing", "Midline crossing"), Trial_type = c("retention",
"retention", "retention", "transfer", "transfer", "transfer",
"transfer", "transfer", "transfer", "retention", "retention",
"retention"), Training = c("left", "left", "left", "right", "right",
"right", "left", "left", "left", "right", "right", "right"),
    N = c(8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8, 8), MovementTime_102 = c(1940.625,
    2200.234375, 1950.078125, 1623.59375, 2266.875, 2608.4375,
    1649.21875, 1690.390625, 3128.660714, 2018.75, 1701.40625,
    2505.703125), MovementTime_104 = c(1601.875, 1658.046875,
    1573.839286, 1435.15625, 2013.359375, 2302.109375, 1390.859375,
    1616.71875, 2399.765625, 1410.625, 1336.40625, 1684.53125
    ), Pathlength_102 = c(2.8680385, 3.872267719, 2.808966672,
    3.184808844, 3.450548063, 2.779296859, 3.057751688, 2.823023969,
    3.831920395, 2.991207031, 2.790851078, 3.276254563), Pathlength_104 = c(2.65516175,
    2.945664516, 2.568061634, 3.017285625, 3.408170609, 2.625024781,
    2.655326156, 2.628399641, 2.975724094, 2.636576609, 2.661606391,
    2.782565766), NormalizedJerk_102 = c(2060.157118, 2981.812369,
    2089.925187, 1391.973644, 3900.411917, 4015.516784, 1411.201689,
    1853.413926, 6830.819063, 2310.589311, 1340.465366, 5617.967587
    ), NormalizedJerk_104 = c(1092.701687, 1508.285476, 1269.670456,
    914.3836443, 2335.718672, 2563.167235, 847.952528, 1394.847247,
    3915.019566, 1023.170254, 765.2752941, 1705.629422), AveResultantVel_102 = c(2.021215719,
    1.994460031, 1.789839578, 2.449869109, 2.037483406, 1.198650234,
    2.374258766, 2.162818172, 1.467132962, 2.101220406, 1.983419094,
    1.595565484), AveResultantVel_104 = c(2.317185313, 2.193130625,
    2.113643324, 2.822947859, 2.213037, 1.311399453, 2.39646225,
    2.113288797, 1.481807047, 2.644351188, 2.54589975, 2.014750766
    ), EndpointError_102 = c(1.62285542, 2.05362611, 2.27036917,
    1.57970041, 1.83768956, 2.14219202, 1.374642, 2.03515938,
    2.58900025, 2.28107478, 1.64171472, 2.13489883), EndpointError_104 = c(0.979220453,
    1.477764016, 1.621229031, 1.239002656, 1.404618047, 1.796644641,
    1.01018125, 1.593606016, 1.672676594, 1.483629813, 1.503123406,
    1.370374047)), class = c("spec_tbl_df", "tbl_df", "tbl",
"data.frame"), row.names = c(NA, -12L), spec = structure(list(
    cols = list(GROUP = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character",
    "collector")), conditon2 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character",
    "collector")), condition = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character",
    "collector")), Trial_type = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character",
    "collector")), Training = structure(list(), class = c("collector_character",
    "collector")), N = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
    "collector")), MovementTime_102 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
    "collector")), MovementTime_104 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
    "collector")), Pathlength_102 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
    "collector")), Pathlength_104 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
    "collector")), NormalizedJerk_102 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
    "collector")), NormalizedJerk_104 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
    "collector")), AveResultantVel_102 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
    "collector")), AveResultantVel_104 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
    "collector")), EndpointError_102 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
    "collector")), EndpointError_104 = structure(list(), class = c("collector_double",
    "collector"))), default = structure(list(), class = c("collector_guess",
    "collector")), skip = 1), class = "col_spec"))
```

```
library(ggplot2)
library(ggalt)  
library(tidyverse)
library(dplyr)
library(showtext)
library(extrafont)
 
font_import()
 
loadfonts(device = "postscript")
#font_add_google("Lato")
 
 
g<- ggplot() +
  geom_segment(data=data10, aes(y=conditon2, yend=conditon2, x=1200, xend=3250), color="#b2b2b2", size=0.15)+
  labs(x=NULL, y=NULL, title="Change in Movement time ms")
 
 
g + geom_dumbbell(data=data10, aes(y=conditon2, x=MovementTime_102, xend=MovementTime_104),
              size=1.5, color="#b2b2b2", size_x=3, size_xend = 3,  colour_x = "red", colour_xend = "blue")
 
 
g + geom_text(data=filter(data10, conditon2=="No Midline crossing_Trans_R"),
              aes(x=MovementTime_104, y=conditon2, label="Pre-Test"),
              color="blue", size=3, vjust=-1.5, fontface="bold", family="Lato") +
  geom_text(data=filter(data10, conditon2=="No Midline crossing_Trans_R"),
            aes(x=MovementTime_102, y=conditon2, label="Post-test"),
            color="red", size=3, vjust=-1.5, fontface="bold", family="Lato")
```

Comment: Hi Reuben. You've shown us the error, but not the code that produced it. It's impossible to debug code that we can't see. Could you possibly edit your question to include the code?

Comment: I just added the code, thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When you're using the `showtext` package with Google fonts, you need to call `showtext_auto()` to ensure that the fonts are made available. Also, the system apparently [doesn't work with the RStudio graphics device](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/showtext/vignettes/introduction.html) so you either need to open an X11 device or save to file.

In this example here, I have recreated your plot and replaced all text elements with the Google font so you can see this is effective:

```
font_add_google("Lato")
showtext_auto()

png("Rplot1.png", width = 600, height = 500, units = "px")

g + geom_dumbbell(data=data10, aes(y    = conditon2, 
                                   x    = MovementTime_102, 
                                   xend = MovementTime_104),
                  size = 1.5, color = "#b2b2b2", size_x = 3, size_xend = 3, 
                  colour_x = "red", colour_xend = "blue") +
    geom_text(data = filter(data10, conditon2 == "No Midline crossing_Trans_R"),
              aes(x = MovementTime_104, y = conditon2, label = "Pre-Test"),
              color = "blue", size = 3, vjust = -1.5, 
              fontface = "bold", family = "Lato") +
    geom_text(data = filter(data10, conditon2 == "No Midline crossing_Trans_R"),
              aes(x = MovementTime_102, y = conditon2, label = "Post-test"),
              color = "red", size = 3, vjust = -1.5, fontface = "bold", 
              family = "Lato") +
    theme(text = element_text(family = "Lato"))

dev.off()
```

And now the file `Rplot1.png` looks like this:

[image]